# Entity Framework 6.0 - Implemeting Optimistic Concurrency with Timestamp Column

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, three-tier

**Background :**
I'm developing a ASP.Net Web Forms Application with EF 6.0 as Data Access. I 3 layers .. Website--> Business --> Data Access ( EF & EDMX is here).. I wanted to handle database concurrency in my code.

My sample table would look like,
**Table** :EmployeeMaster
**Columns**: EmpID, EMpName, Address, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn (DataTime)

I tried implementing the optimistic concurrency as explained in few blogs, by having a Column "ConcurrencyCheck" in DB with a datatype "timestamp" and setting the concurrency mode to "Fixed" in the model. It worked well. However I feel that having one additional column in almost all my tables ( I have around 50 tables) would be bit odd.

**Question:**
Is there a way where I can use on of my existing column for concurrency check and achieve optimistic concurrency ?

I tried setting my exisiting column **"UpdatedOn"** ( datetime column , not nullable) with concurrency mode as "Fixed". Concurrency check was happening. However when I do an update I'm not able to update the latest time into that field since it has the previos timestamp in it to perform the concurrency check.

Note : I'm aware that EF would add the column that I mark as Concurrency Mode "Fixed" to its where clause and achieve the desired result. I'm creating the DB Context every time when we call methods.

Comment: You have to write a trigger that updates `UpdatedOn` when the record is updated. Or use the rowversion data type.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gert. Using rowversion data type means I need to have a new column at the DB with this type right ?

Comment: If you want to hang on to `UpdatedOn` (which is sensible, I think), yes.